# Insert statement with subquery and extra column

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, sql-insert, dao

I want to use insert statement with select subquery from another table. In my case, I want to add a row from `PRESENTATION` table to `AVAILABILITY` table.

`AVAILABILITY` table structure:

```
availableID        (number, generated using sequence)
availableDay       (varchar)
availableStart     (varchar)
availableEnd       (varchar)
lecturerID(FK)     (varchar)
presentationID(FK) (number, generated using sequence)
```

`PRESENTATION` table structure:

```
presentationID         (number, generated using sequence)
presentationDay        (varchar)
presentationStart      (varchar)
presentationEnd        (varchar)
```

I tried to construct the query in DAO like this :

```
        String lecturerID = Abean.getLecturerID();
        String availableDay = Abean.getAvailableDay();
        String availableStart = Abean.getAvailableStart();
        String availableEnd = Abean.getAvailableEnd();
        Date availableDate = Abean.getAvailableDate();
        String presentationID = Abean.getPresentationID();

    try{  

            currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("
            insert into availability (availableID,
                                      lecturerID,
                                      availableDay,
                                      availableStart,
                                      availableEnd,
                                      presentationid) 
           select(availabilityseq.nextval,
                  ?,
                  presentationDay,
                  presentationStart,
                  presentationEnd,
                  presentationid) 
                  from presentation where presentationid=?

            ");  
            ps.setString(1,Abean.getLecturerID());  
            ps.setString(2,Abean.getAvailableDay());  
            ps.setString(3,Abean.getAvailableStart()); 
            ps.setString(4,Abean.getAvailableEnd());  
            ps.setString(5,Abean.getPresentationID()); 
           // ps.setString(6,Abean.getAvailableID());
            ps.executeUpdate();  

            }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("add availability 2 failed: An Exception has occurred! " + e);
    }
```

As expected, it return error

ERROR: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index`

So, how can i do insert with subquery with extra column?

**UPDATE: MY DAO codes**

Comment: did yo specify the bind variable twice?

Comment: notice that in the subquery, the where clause is `presentation id=?` should be `presentationid=?`

Comment: My bad.. But after i change it, same error occur. Maybe i should show the rest of my DAO?

Comment: maybe you should indeed

Comment: you're query has only 2 question marks, but you supply 5 bind variables ??

Comment: do i have to do something like `values (?,?,?,?,?)` ?? Is that what you mean?

Comment: you need to understand what you're doing. where are the values for the new row coming from? if they all come from the Java code, then why do you need the subquery? you need to decide what is the relation of the two tables and how they are populated? where are the values coming from?

Comment: The new row coming from `PRESENTATION` table retrieved by `presentationID` chosen by user. Means that only `presentationID` comes from JAVA code.

Comment: so what is `Abean`? where does it come from and why do you set 5 bind variables in the prepared stmt??

Comment: `Abean` is from Availability Bean. Cause..... Isn't that how it works? I don't understand. Sorry :(

Comment: first of all, the number of bind variables that you supply with `setString()` have to match the number of "?" symbols that you specify in the SQL text. It seems that in the SQL text you copy column values from `PRESENTATION` into `availability`, however, the use of `ABean` suggests that the values come from that Java Object. so which is which?

Comment: let's take one column as example - `availableDay` - it is either populated from `presentationDay` or from `Abean.getAvailableDay()` but cannot from both.

Comment: populated from `presentationDay`..

Comment: in that case, do not supply `Abean.getAvailableDay()` as bind variable. seems like you need to specify `ps.setString(1,Abean.getPresentationID());`  and again with index 2 , to match the "?" symbols in ther SQL text

Comment: So i have to specify which bean for `Abean.getAvailableDay()` since its come from table `PRESENTATION`. Symbol `?` is to match value `lecturerID`. This ID is depends on current user who insert the data. `lecturerID' does not exist in `PRESENTATION` table

Comment: what do you mean " which bean for Abean.getAvailableDay()"? this doesn't make sense. you dont need `Abean.getAvailableDay()` at all if the value for column `availableDay` comes from column `presentationDay` . your sql text seems fine, but you need to fix the `ps.setString` to match the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the setting of bind variables values with the bind variables specification in the SQL text :

**EDIT Apr 18th:** removed parenthesis from select subquery

```
PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("
            insert into availability (availableID,
                                      lecturerID,
                                      availableDay,
                                      availableStart,
                                      availableEnd,
                                      presentationid) 
           select availabilityseq.nextval,
                  ?,
                  presentationDay,
                  presentationStart,
                  presentationEnd,
                  presentationid
                  from presentation where presentationid=?
            ");  
            ps.setString(1,Abean.getLecturerID());  // match first "?"
            ps.setString(2,Abean.getPresentationID());    // match 2nd "?"
```

Comment: I am getting `NullPointerException` but it retrieve the right `presentationID` and `lecturerID`. I checked using S.O.P the `availabilityDay`,`availabilityStart` and `availabilityEnd` were null

Comment: where are you getting it?

Comment: what do the presentationDay/Start/End contain for the specified `Abean.getPresentationID()`

Comment: I'm sorry.. what do you mean? Can you give example?

Comment: example of what? I am asking you to debug/print the value of `Abean.getPresentationID()` and see what are the values of the row in presentation table

Comment: Ohh haha. Well i get `581` for example, as i choose the ID. It should give me :  Day: `Wednesday` Start: `08.00 AM`  End: `10.00 AM`

Comment: from the day, start and end...?

Comment: you mean when you fetch the row that was just inserted?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea why the null values. the SQL seems correct to my eyes

Comment: Day, start and end should be null right? because I'm not retrieving the value from servlet.... Does that make sense?

Comment: Day, start and end are not taken from servlet. they are taken from `presentation` table row where `presentationID = 581`

Comment: Yes. That's what i thought. Wonder what is the problem -.-

Comment: you need to run the insert statement in an SQL client/editor, with the bind variables substituted and see what happens like this:
 
insert into availability (availableID, lecturerID, availableDay, availableStart, availableEnd, presentationid) 
select(availabilityseq.nextval, 581, presentationDay, presentationStart, presentationEnd, presentationid) from presentation where presentationid=581

Comment: i got `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. The error between `availability.nextval,.....` I will try again. I am not satisfied haha

Comment: insert into availability (availableID, lecturerID, availableDay, availableStart, availableEnd, presentationid) select availabilityseq.nextval, 581, presentationDay, presentationStart, presentationEnd, presentationid from presentation where presentationid=581

Comment: you also need to correct the SQL text in the Java code, see edited answer

Comment: AHHHHH That's a silly mistake. Worked on SQL. But still getting NPE in java. Trying to solve it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Still not working out honestly. Getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: SOLVED. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes :D. Thank you again @sharonbn. I owe you big time hehe